# I go to W3C for definitive guidance on HTML, where do I go for DNS?

Tags: dns

Where can I go to find the definitive answer to questions like the following?

'What makes a naked CNAME record break email on the domain?'

I would use W3C for HTML, or php.net for PHP - but is there a guiding body for DNS?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Standards

Comment: Also: https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain/613830#613830

Answer (score 0):

DNS is defined by RFCs published by the IETF.

https://www.ietf.org/